# How to convert multicast to h265

Tags: ffmpeg

I am trying to use latest ffmpeg.

```
ffmpeg -r 25 -i  "udp://lo@238.108.108.11:1234? overrun_nonfatal=1&fifo_size=50000000" -c:v libx265 -preset ultrafast -x265-params crf=23 -strict experimental -f mpegts udp://lo@238.108.108.11:1234
```

and have error.
How to convert input mpeg-4 stream to h265?

Answer (score 0):

you are download the stream from `238.108.108.11:1234` and trying to upload it to the same group. if ffmpeg will do it, then it should download all recent uploaded data and the again and again. try to upload encoded data to another group or another port if you would like the group is same.